# Xamarin.form(XAML)のLabelタグの複数行表示について(多言語対応)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

アプリの多言語対応でLabelの複数行表示で困っております。

以下の日本語を「AppResources.resx」ファイルに設定しております。

```html
    <data name="aaa" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>あああ</value>
    </data>
    <data name="bbb" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>いいい</value>
    </data>
    <data name="ccc" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>ううう</value>
    </data>
```

また、xamlファイルには以下のLabelタグを定義しております。

```html
<Label TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White">
  <Label.Text>
    {i18n:Translate aaa}
    {i18n:Translate bbb}
    {i18n:Translate ccc}
  </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

この状態でiOSシミュレータで確認すると、「AppResources.resx」で定義した日本語ではなく

```
    {i18n:Translate aaa}
    {i18n:Translate bbb}
    {i18n:Translate ccc}
```

と表示します。
Labelタグに日本語を含む多言語を複数行表示するには
どのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか。
ご教授のほどお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`Label.FormattedText` を試してみてください。

以下のように書けば期待する結果になると思います。

```
<Label TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{i18n:Translate aaa}" />
            <Span Text="{x:Static x:Environment.NewLine}" />
            <Span Text="{i18n:Translate bbb}" />
            <Span Text="{x:Static x:Environment.NewLine}" />
            <Span Text="{i18n:Translate ccc}" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

よろしければ、私のブログ記事も合わせてどうぞ。
http://ticktack.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/02/11/175656